# Eliciting states and counties with Alexa

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have a skill that elicits a U.S. state and county from the user and then retrieves some data. The backend is working fine, but I am concerned about how to structure the conversation. So far, I have created an intent called GetInfoIntent, which has two custom slots, state_name, and county_name

There are about 3,000 U.S. counties with many duplicate names. It seems silly to me that I am asking for a county, without first "narrowing down", by states. Another way I can think of to do the conversation is to have 50 intents, "GetNewHampshireInfo, GetCaliforniaInfo, etc. If I did it this way, I'd need a custom slot type for each state, like nh_counties, ca_counties. etc.

This must be a pretty generic problem. Is there a standard approach, or best practice, I can use?

Answer (score 0):

My (not necessarily best practice) practice tips:

1. Single slot for single data type. Meaning only have one slot for a four digit number even if you use it in more than one place for two different things in the skill.
2. As few intents as you need
   no more no less. You certainly can and should break up the back end code with helper code, but try and not break the intents into too many smaller pieces. It can lead to difficulty when Alexa is trying to choose the intended intent.
3. Keep it voice focused. How would you ask in a
   conversation. Voice first development is always the way to go.

For the slot filling I think it is fine to ask both state and county. 
If the matching is not correct ask for confirmation.

Another option is to not use auto filling within the Alexa skill and use the dialog interface. Ask the county first and then only when it has more than one state option and is ambiguous continue the dialog to fill the state.

Even if you did have 50 separate intents you really never want to have two slots that can be filled by the same word. For example having a mo_counties and ky_counties that Clack satisfies both is ambiguous and can cause unneeded difficultly.

So for someone looking for the "best practice" I have learning that there isn't one yet (maybe never will be). Do what makes sense for the conversation and try and keep it as simple as it needs to be and no less on the back end.

I also find it helpful to find a non-developer to test your conversation flow.

This wasn't really technical and is all opinion, but that is a lot of what Alexa development is. I would suggest Tuesday Alexa office hours at https://www.twitch.tv/amazonalexa very helpful and you can ask questions about stuff like this.

Comment: Thanks very much, especially the suggestion about twitch tv. I am currently in the midst of implementing 50 stage intents, with each intent having a special counties slot, so MA_Intent would have MA_counties as a slot, etc. This may be wrongheaded overkill, but it will be burned into my memory, if it fails spectacularly. I am working by editing the conversational JSON which is getting truly massive.